# Filling inner part of svg

Tags: svg

probably super easy question, but I have no idea how to use svgs. We have got the code:

```
<svg height="16px" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 16 16" width="16px" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:sketch="http://www.bohemiancoding.com/sketch/ns" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><title/><defs/><g fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd" id="Icons with numbers" stroke="none" stroke-width="1"><g fill="#000000" id="Group" transform="translate(-48.000000, -432.000000)"><path d="M54.8796844,443.0591 L54.8796844,445 L57.2307692,445 L57.2307692,443.0591 Z M56,448 C51.5817218,448 48,444.418278 48,440 C48,435.581722 51.5817218,432 56,432 C60.4182782,432 64,435.581722 64,440 C64,444.418278 60.4182782,448 56,448 Z M53.5700197,435.51041 C52.5864514,436.043208 52.0631167,436.947609 52,438.22364 L54.2800789,438.22364 C54.2800789,437.852024 54.4076253,437.493845 54.6627219,437.149093 C54.9178185,436.804341 55.3504243,436.631968 55.9605523,436.631968 C56.5811997,436.631968 57.0085458,436.771881 57.2426036,437.051713 C57.4766613,437.331544 57.5936884,437.641592 57.5936884,437.981867 C57.5936884,438.277369 57.4884955,438.548241 57.2781065,438.794493 L56.8205128,439.190732 L56.2445759,439.573539 C55.6765258,439.949633 55.3241295,440.282067 55.1873767,440.570853 C55.0506239,440.859639 54.9664696,441.382356 54.9349112,442.139019 L57.0650888,442.139019 C57.0703485,441.780835 57.1045362,441.516679 57.1676529,441.346541 C57.2675876,441.077903 57.4700839,440.842849 57.7751479,440.64137 L58.3353057,440.271995 C58.9033559,439.895901 59.28731,439.586972 59.4871795,439.345198 C59.8290615,438.946718 60,438.456461 60,437.874412 C60,436.925225 59.6068415,436.208867 58.8205128,435.725319 C58.0341841,435.241771 57.0466858,435 55.8579882,435 C54.9533157,435 54.1906671,435.170135 53.5700197,435.51041 Z M53.5700197,435.51041"    id="Oval 318"/></g></g></svg>
```

which gives us a question mark. But how can I fill with color the actual question mark, not only the black circle ?

Answer (score 0):

The `<path>` element provides you with a black circle containing a cut-out question mark. To fill the question mark, just put it on top of a circle with the required fill colour.

I've fixed your coordinates a bit in the following example:

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 16 16">
  <circle r="7" fill="#ff0" transform="translate(8,8)" />
  <path d="M6.88,11.059 L6.88,13 L9.231,13 L9.231,11.059 Z M8,16 C3.582,16 0,12.418
           0,8 C0,3.582 3.582,0 8,0 C12.418,0 16,3.582 16,8 C16,12.418 12.418,16 8,16
           Z M5.57,3.51 C4.586,4.043 4.063,4.948 4,6.224 L6.28,6.224 C6.28,5.852
           6.408,5.494 6.663,5.149 C6.918,4.804 7.35,4.632 7.961,4.632 C8.581,4.632
           9.009,4.772 9.243,5.052 C9.477,5.332 9.594,5.642 9.594,5.982 C9.594,6.277
           9.488,6.548 9.278,6.794 L8.821,7.191 L8.245,7.574 C7.677,7.95 7.324,8.282
           7.187,8.571 C7.051,8.86 6.966,9.382 6.935,10.139 L9.065,10.139 C9.07,9.781
           9.105,9.517 9.168,9.347 C9.268,9.078 9.47,8.843 9.775,8.641 L10.335,8.272
           C10.903,7.896 11.287,7.587 11.487,7.345 C11.829,6.947 12,6.456 12,5.874
           C12,4.925 11.607,4.209 10.821,3.725 C10.034,3.242 9.047,3 7.858,3 C6.953,3
           6.191,3.17 5.57,3.51 Z M5.57,3.513" fill="#000" fill-rule="evenodd" />
</svg>
```